# Difficulties in centering the Navbar UL items vertically

Tags: html, css, alignment, navbar, center

First of all, I'm a newbie on front-end. Sorry for any inconveniences.

I'm having some difficulties centering the Navbar UL vertically. For example, notice that the logo is centered vertically correctly. However, the UL items are aligned slightly above the central vertical axis.

**Snippet link:** https://codepen.io/samuluizzz/pen/YzeyNgr

**HTML:**

```
    <nav class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html"><img style="border-style: solid; border-width: 1px black; border-radius: 50%" src="img/logo-navbar.png" height="60" width="60"></a>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul class="list">
                <li><a href="#info">info</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus">about us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#share">share</a></li>
                <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-dark"><a href="#quiz">quiz</a></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="btn" id="toggler"><i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i></button>
    </nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
 ​.​navbar​ { 
 ​    ​display​:​ flex; 
 ​    ​flex-wrap​:​ wrap; 
 ​    ​align-items​:​ center; 
 ​    ​justify-content​:​ space-between; 
 ​    ​background-color​:​ white; 
 ​    ​padding​:​ ​15​px​; 
 ​    ​border-bottom​:​ dotted ​1​px​ ​rgba​(​0​,​ ​0​,​ ​0​,​ ​0.25​); 
 ​} 
 ​.​navbar​ .​logo​ { 
 ​    ​margin-right​:​ ​50​px​; 
 ​} 
 ​.​navbar​ .​list​{ 
 ​    ​display​:​ flex; 
 ​    ​align-items​:​ center; 
 ​    ​list-style​:​ none; 
 ​    ​gap​:​ ​25​px​; 
 ​} 
 ​.​navbar​ ​a​{ 
 ​    ​text-decoration​:​ none; 
 ​    ​color​:​ inherit; 
 ​} 
 ​.​navbar​ ​a​:​hover​{ 
 ​    ​color​:​slategray; 
 ​} 
 ​#​toggler​, 
 ​.​navbar​ ​i​ { 
 ​    ​display​:​ none; 
 ​}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using a library or something that has a `reboot` file

basically these files are to fix unwanted default values but your reboot is doing it weird, it's adding a margin-bottom to your `ul` elements which is causing your problem

[image: this is it]

```
ul{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

OR

```
.list{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Will fix it

====== UPDATE  =======

I've tested your code inside jsFiddle and it does not have any problem!

https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiar_mansouri/wj2uf49y/3/

here you can check it out yourself, so test it in your own browser and inspect your `ul.list` if it had that margin, remove it and let me know if otherwise

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
In fact, the problem appears when I import the Bootstrap.
Besides the snippet on CodePen, I'm using VSCode and Live Server to see the website.

Comment: The margin-bottom on the list class solved the problem. Thanks!